# SFTP post upload hook

Tags: debian, ftp, sftp, chroot, hook

How would I run a script after a file has been successfully uploaded over (a chrooted) SFTP?

I have this working on standard FTP connection using PureFTP

http://linux.die.net/man/8/pure-uploadscript

I'm running Debian Squeeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with [ProFTPd](http://www.proftpd.org/) & the [`mod_exec`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_exec.html) module.

Comment: Please update your solution. mod_exec link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). This uses the kernel's inotify hooks to run arbitrary commands on specified filesystem events.